# How far do chests render from?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking around Google, I've gotten no answers. The wiki page said nothing about rendering. How far do chests render from? Are they like normal blocks? In other words, how far away do you have to be from a chest in order for it to disappear?

Comment: Could he be confusing with the way chests are rendered (well more like "suddenly appear out of nowhere when you get close; 10 blocks") with the anti-xray bukkit plugins out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of performance reasons. See Jeb's comment on [MC-3336](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-3336?focusedCommentId=47953&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-47953).

I tested render distances of various entities and the following is the result I got:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                      Entity                        | Disappear |   Appear  |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Item                                               |        16 |        16 |
| Leash Knot                                         |        32 |        32 |
| Painting                                           |        45 |        45 |
| Minecart                                           |        57 |        57 |
| Chest, Sign, Banner, Skull, Enchanting Table Book  |        64 |        64 |
| Boat                                               |        77 |        77 |
| Mobs                                               |        82 |        77 |
| Armor Stand, Item Frame                            |       146 |       142 |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

All numbers are in meters(blocks).

Comment: What render distance did you have in settings when testing this?

Comment: What are the two different numbers you have there? For example you have `Mobs 82 77`. What does 82 mean and what does 77 mean?

Comment: @LyonesGamer 16 Chunks. I doubt that render distance affects entity rendering unless chunk is unloaded.

Comment: @Ben Entity disappearing / appearing in blocks. Mobs will stop render after you move further away 82 blocks and start render again when you get inside 77 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Chests alone do not count as entities (they are blocks), so they will disappear as soon as the chunk that they are located in is unloaded.

See: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks

Comment: I have a chunk loaded with a chest located at sky limit. I can't see the chest from the ground, but I can when I go higher up. Why is that, if a chest appears when a chunk is loaded?

Comment: @crgsqdmn I believe that is to do with render distance.

Answer (score 0):

Chests are normal blocks. They open and close, but still they are normal blocks. As for "how far so that they disappear", that depends on everyone's client's render distance settings. If you set to 1, then everything outside your 50-block range will disappear. If you set to 16, then the chest can be seen even at 800 blocks far. As soon as they leave your render distance, they disappear. (But they're still there! It's not completely GONE.)